# Laravel- Why do I get a parse error when writing HTML inside an @if in a blade.php file?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I'm working on a Laravel/ Angular application, and on one of the pages, there is the functionality to export some information that a user has entered into a form to a PDF.

The PDF is written in a blade.php file with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App - Provisional Reminder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('') }}/css/pdf.css">
</head>

<body style="...">
    @foreach ($items as $item)
        <table>
            ... HTML here...
        </table>

        @if($item['itemDetail']['itemProperty'] !== 'ParticularItemProperty')
            <p style="page-break-before: always"></p>
            @include('pdfs.partials.request')
        @endif
        ... A few more simiar @if statements here...
    @endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment, the PDF always consists of three pages (each one displaying information about a particular aspect of the information that the user has entered into the form.

I want to make the content of the PDF that's generated conditional, based on the value of an `itemProperty` of any of the items that are being exported to PDF by the user.

I tried surrounding the content of the PDF with an `@if`, `@else` & `@endif` statement:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App - Provisional Reminder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('') }}/css/pdf.css">
<head>

@if(( count( {{ $item['itemDetail'] }} ) === 1 ) && ({{ $item['itemDetail']['itemProperty'] }} === '1010'))
<body style="...">
    <p>if statement run in blade.php</p>
</body>
@else
<body>
    <p>else statement run in blade.php</p>
</body>
@endif

</html>
```

I couldn't get the original content of the blade.php file to be displayed conditionally within my `@if`, `@else` & `@endif` PHP statements, so just tried displaying some very basic HTML instead- as above, just to see that the code was actually running/ being generated correctly.

However, when I click the link to generate & download the PDF with this code in the blade.php file that will be generated, I get a message in the browser that says:

> There was a problem generating the PDF

and the browser console says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: /.../blade.php)

Why is the `@if` causing this error? The HTML is clearly fine, as it is displayed properly if I remove the `@if` and download the file.

I think it must be to do with the PHP variables that I'm referencing within the `@if()` statement, as if I change the `@if()` to something simple, like:

```
@if( 1 === 1)
```

and then try to download the PDF, it downloads and opens correctly, and I can see the text stating `if statement run in reminder.blade.php` displayed on the page in the PDF.

What am I doing wrong in how I'm referencing the PHP variables that I'm basing my `@if()` on?

Comment: `@if(( count( {{ $item['itemDetail'] }} ) === 1 ) && ({{ $item['itemDetail']['itemProperty'] }} === '1010'))` - why do you have `{{ }}` in this `if` statement? They shouldn't to be there. `{{ }}` is used to simply echo out values.

Comment: When using `@stuff`  you are already in template context (parser) so no need to use another template function `{{}}` coz already you in one; parser tries to treat it as php code which messes things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App - Provisional Reminder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('') }}/css/pdf.css">
<head>

@if(( count(  $item['itemDetail']  ) === 1 ) && ( $item['itemDetail']['itemProperty']  === '1010'))
<body style="...">
    <p>if statement run in blade.php</p>
</body>
@else
<body>
    <p>else statement run in blade.php</p>
</body>
@endif

</html>
```

Using {{ }} in blade is only for echoing a string value to the view. It's the same as

`<?php echo $item['itemDetail'] ; ?>`  which makes no sense inside an if statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty new to Laravel/ PHP, so didn't realise I wouldn't need the braces. I tried what you suggested, and removed the `{{ }}`, but I now get `undefined variable: item` in the console when trying to download the PDF- do I need reference/ use the PHP Controller file where the variable is defined/ initialised from within the blade.php file somehow?

Comment: You are close. You need to return your values from your controller to the view so you can  access them there. It's kinda of returning values from a function but instead laravel allows you to return them on blade and use them there   Check this link for more help : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views

Comment: Ok, thanks. So given that `$item` is a variable whose value will be determined based on options selected by the user, how would I pass that in? The link you've posted seems to show how to pass in String variables, but my `$item` variable here is a much more complex data type...

Comment: You can also pass arrays not only strings.  It works like a normal return works. The way you handle the array is up to you but i guess you will need a loop in your blade if that's the case.

Comment: The variable's not an array though, it's an object- with multiple properties- some of those properties themselves also being complex data types.

Comment: Please read through the documentation. You can also pass stdclass object but as i said you have to handle them in the blade if you want to populate a multidimensional array or object data.

Comment: I've tried adding a new route to my routes/web.php file with: `Route::get('view', function() { return view('reminder.blade', $item); });`, I still get the same `undefined variable: item` error in the console when trying to download the PDF- any idea what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: Also tried doing it using the PHP function that's performing the request to generate the PDF: `Route::post('getSingleItemPDF', 'WebApi\ProvController@getSingleItemPDF');`, but I still get the `undefined vairable: item` error in the console... not sure why/ what I'm doing wrong here?